# What's the usual strategy for developing and testing a python package?

Tags: python-3.x, python-module, python-packaging

I'm developing a body of Python modules to be used as a package.  The tentative file layout is:

```
my_project/
  core/
    foo.py
    bar.py
    ...
  test/
    test_foo.py
    test_bar.py
  examples/
    example0.py
```

A few questions:

- I've seen conflicting info on whether I need **init**.py -- perhaps that restriction was lifted in python3?  Do I just want a top-level `my_module.py` that lists the core modules?
- What's the pythonic way to make the module discoverable LOCALLY?  That is, I'd like to be able run example0.py without having to do `pip install my_project` (or the equivalent) each time I make a change to the core files?
- Parallel question for making the module discoverable to the unit test files...

Comment: This can actually help you : https://medium.com/theleanprogrammer/publish-your-first-python-package-on-pypi-3079d409792f

Comment: @SARANSURYA They Medium article will be useful for when I publish the package - thanks.  In the meantime, I need to figure out the right way to set up PYTHONPATH, etc, so I can run the tests and examples.

Comment: I'm voting to close my own question.  I will post a better, more concrete question, replete with "this is what I tried" and "this is what happened" which will be more useful for future readers.